# Policy-based OR role-based authorization in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, blazor-webassembly

I'm using Blazor WASM to build web application and for some page I'd like to implement authorization with following logic: user can access this page if his role is `Admin` OR he corresponds to specific policy.

I've tried this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin", Policy = "Policy")]
```

but it checks both conditions.

Comment: Is this a pattern that you repeat with a few different policies, or is it always the same policy you're looking for? You could make another policy which includes the check for an admin

Comment: Policy based authorization can include testing roles. So just add another policy...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a requirement:

```
public class CustomPolicyRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

Then create a handler:

```
public class CustomPolicyHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CustomPolicyRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CustomPolicyRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.IsInRole(nameof(RoleName.Admin))
        // Check if user corresponds a policy
            || context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email && c.Value == "aboba@gmail.com")) 
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Finally, add a policy and register handler:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(opt =>
{
    opt.AddPolicy("Policy", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new CustomPolicyRequirement()));
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CustomPolicyHandler>();
```